# Spacing issue with HTML/CSS. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Tags: html, css, formatting, spacing

[My output overlayed over desired output](http://oi67.tinypic.com/x0pu04.jpg):

I'm essentially trying to replicate the webpage output for this [assignment](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse154/16wi/homework/2/spec.pdf). Pictures used in webpage are [here](https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/).

I've tried battering my head against it for the last few hours and I just can't figure out what's wrong.

The block elements that make up the columns are staggered downwards as you can see in the picture. The only code that adjusts the vertical spacing adjusts it by 20pts, which is the requirement by the specification.

I'm also not sure how to get it to extend past the container as it does in the output. In my version of the file, it stops at the end of the container.

Am I just completely misunderstanding what needs to be done here? Is this some other error I'm completely familiar with?

```css
#banner {
 height: 50px;
 background-image: url(https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rancidbannerbg.png);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#banner img {
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

body {
 background-image: url(https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/moviebg.png);
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 10pt;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

#column-left, #column-right {
 margin-right: 2%;
 width: 47%;
}

#column-left {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 2%;
}

#column-right {
 float: right;
}

#container {
 background-color: #EEEEEE;
 border-radius: 20px;
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray;
 margin: auto;
 width: 800px;
}

#date {
 background-color: #A2B964;
 clear: both;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: center;
}

h1, .reviewer-text {
 font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 24pt;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 3px 3px #999999;
}

#logo {
 background-image: url(https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rottenlargebg.png);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 height: 83px;
 font-size: 48pt;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: red;
}

#logo img {
 vertical-align: bottom;
}

.publication {
 font-style: italic;
}

#reviews {
 width: 550px;
}

.reviewer-info {
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.reviewer-info img, .reviewer-text img {
 float: left;
 margin-right: 5px;
}

.reviewer-text {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
 border-radius: 20px;
 padding-top: 8px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
 padding-left: 8px;
 padding-right: 8px;
}

#general-overview {
 width: 250px;
 background-color: #A2B964;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 float: right;
}

#general-overview dt {
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-top: 10pt;
 padding-left: 10pt;
}

#general-overview dd {
 padding-left: 10pt;
 padding-right: 10pt;
}

#general-overview ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

#validators {
 bottom: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 position: fixed;
 opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div id = "banner">
 <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rancidbanner.png" alt="Rancid Tomatoes" />
</div>

<h1>TMNT (2007)</h1>

<div id="container">
 <div id="general-overview">
  <div>
   <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/overview.png" alt="general overview" />
  </div>

  <dl>
   <dt>STARRING</dt>
   <dd>Patrick Stewart <br /> Mako <br /> Sarah Michelle Gellar <br /> Kevin Smith</dd>

   <dt>DIRECTOR</dt>
   <dd>Kevin Munroe</dd>

   <dt>RATING</dt>
   <dd>PG</dd>

   <dt>THEATRICAL RELEASE</dt>
   <dd>Mar 23, 2007</dd>

   <dt>MOVIE SYNOPSIS</dt>
   <dd>After the defeat of their old arch nemesis, The Shredder, the Turtles have grown apart as a family.</dd>

   <dt>MPAA RATING</dt>
   <dd>PG, for animated action violence, some scary cartoon images and mild language</dd>

   <dt>RELEASE COMPANY</dt>
   <dd>Warner Bros.</dd>

   <dt>RUNTIME</dt>
   <dd>90 mins</dd>

   <dt>GENRE</dt>
   <dd>Action/Adventure, Comedies, Childrens, Martial Arts, Superheroes, Ninjas, Animated Characters</dd>

   <dt>BOX OFFICE</dt>
   <dd>$54,132,596</dd>

   <dt>LINKS</dt>
   <dd>
    <br />
    <ul>
     <li><a href="http://www.ninjaturtles.com/">The Official TMNT Site</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/teenage_mutant_ninja_turtles/">RT Review</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://www.rottentomatoes.com/">RT Home</a></li>

    </ul>
   </dd>
  </dl>
 </div>

 <div id="reviews"> 
  <div id="logo">
   <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rottenlarge.png" alt="Rotten" />
   33%
  </div>

  <div id="column-left">
   <p class="reviewer-text">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
    <q>Ditching the cheeky, self-aware wink that helped to excuse the concept's inherent corniness, the movie attempts to look polished and 'cool,' but the been-there animation can't compete with the     then-cutting-edge puppetry of the 1990 live-action movie.</q>    
  </p>    
  <p class="reviewer-info">
       <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
       Peter Debruge <br />
       <span class="publication">Variety</span>
  </p>    

   <p class="reviewer-text">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/fresh.gif" alt="Fresh" />
    <q>TMNT is a fun, action-filled adventure that will satisfy longtime fans and generate a legion of new ones.</q>
   </p>
   <p class="reviewer-info">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
    Todd Gilchrist <br />
    <span class="publication">IGN Movies</span>
   </p>

   <p class="reviewer-text">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
    <q>It stinks!</q>
   </p>
   <p class="reviewer-info">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
    Jay Sherman (unemployed)
   </p>

   <p class="reviewer-text">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
    <q>The rubber suits are gone and they've been redone with fancy computer technology, but that hasn't stopped them from becoming dull.</q>
   </p>
   <p class="reviewer-info">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
    Joshua Tyler <br />
    <span class="publication">CinemaBlend.com</span>
   </p>

   <p class="reviewer-text">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
    <q>This movie sucks because reasons.</q>
   </p>
   <p class="reviewer-info">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
    T. Tally Nobias <br />
    <span class="publication">objectivereviews.com</span>
   </p>
  </div>

  <div id="column-right">
   <p class="reviewer-text">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
    <q>The turtles themselves may look prettier, but are no smarter; torn irreparably from their countercultural roots, our superheroes on the half shell have been firmly co-opted by the industry their creators     once sought to spoof.</q>
  </p>    
  <p class="reviewer-info">
       <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
       Jeannette Catsoulis <br />
       <span class="publication">New York Times</span>
  </p>    

   <p class="reviewer-text">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
    <q>Impersonally animated and arbitrarily plotted, the story appears to have been made up as the filmmakers went along.</q>
   </p>
   <p class="reviewer-info">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
    Ed Gonzalez <br />
    <span class="publication">Slant Magazine</span>
   </p>

   <p class="reviewer-text">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/fresh.gif" alt="Fresh" />
    <q>The striking use of image and motion allows each sequence to leave an impression. It's an accomplished restart to this franchise.</q>
   </p>
   <p class="reviewer-info">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
    Mark Palermo <br />
    <span class="publication">Coast (Halifax, Nova Scotia)</span>
   </p>

   <p class="reviewer-text">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
    <q>The script feels like it was computer generated. This mechanical presentation lacks the cheesy charm of the three live action films.</q>
   </p>
   <p class="reviewer-info">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
    Steve Rhodes <br />
    <span class="publication">Internet Reviews</span>
   </p>

   <p class="reviewer-text">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
    <q>This movie is literally the worst movie ever. I'm not going to explain why. -10000000/10.</q>
   </p>
   <p class="reviewer-info">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
    A. Rheal Kritik <br />
    <span class="publication">Facade Inc.</span>
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <p id="date">(1-10) of 88</p>
</div>

<div id="validators">
 <a href="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/validate-html.php"><img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/w3c-html.png" alt="Valid HTML5" /></a><br />
 <a href="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/validate-css.php"><img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/w3c-css.png" alt="Valid CSS" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The block elements that make up the columns are staggered downwards as you can see in the picture. The only code that adjusts the vertical spacing adjusts it by 20pts, which is the requirement by the specification.

I can't comment yet (>49 rep needed // ok, earned them after posting this answer), can you explain this one? For me it looks like in the picture (or maybe I'm looking at wrong elements).

> I'm also not sure how to get it to extend past the container as it does in the output. In my version of the file, it stops at the end of the container.

You can easily achieve that by adding bottom margin to your `#container` element:

```
#container {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray;
    /* margin: top right bottom left; */
    margin: 0px auto 20px auto;
    width: 800px;
}
```

```css
#banner {
 height: 50px;
 background-image: url(https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rancidbannerbg.png);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#banner img {
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

body {
 background-image: url(https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/moviebg.png);
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 10pt;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

#column-left, #column-right {
 margin-right: 2%;
 width: 47%;
}

#column-left {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 2%;
}

#column-right {
 float: right;
}

#container {
 background-color: #EEEEEE;
 border-radius: 20px;
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray;
 margin: 0px auto 20px auto;
 width: 800px;
}

#date {
 background-color: #A2B964;
 clear: both;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: center;
}

h1, .reviewer-text {
 font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 24pt;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 3px 3px #999999;
}

#logo {
 background-image: url(https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rottenlargebg.png);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 height: 83px;
 font-size: 48pt;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: red;
}

#logo img {
 vertical-align: bottom;
}

.publication {
 font-style: italic;
}

#reviews {
 width: 550px;
}

.reviewer-info {
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.reviewer-info img, .reviewer-text img {
 float: left;
 margin-right: 5px;
}

.reviewer-text {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
 border-radius: 20px;
 padding-top: 8px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
 padding-left: 8px;
 padding-right: 8px;
}

#general-overview {
 width: 250px;
 background-color: #A2B964;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 float: right;
}

#general-overview dt {
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-top: 10pt;
 padding-left: 10pt;
}

#general-overview dd {
 padding-left: 10pt;
 padding-right: 10pt;
}

#general-overview ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

#validators {
 bottom: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 position: fixed;
 opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div id = "banner">
 <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rancidbanner.png" alt="Rancid Tomatoes" />
</div>

<h1>TMNT (2007)</h1>

<div id="container">
 <div id="general-overview">
  <div>
   <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/overview.png" alt="general overview" />
  </div>

  <dl>
   <dt>STARRING</dt>
   <dd>Patrick Stewart <br /> Mako <br /> Sarah Michelle Gellar <br /> Kevin Smith</dd>

   <dt>DIRECTOR</dt>
   <dd>Kevin Munroe</dd>

   <dt>RATING</dt>
   <dd>PG</dd>

   <dt>THEATRICAL RELEASE</dt>
   <dd>Mar 23, 2007</dd>

   <dt>MOVIE SYNOPSIS</dt>
   <dd>After the defeat of their old arch nemesis, The Shredder, the Turtles have grown apart as a family.</dd>

   <dt>MPAA RATING</dt>
   <dd>PG, for animated action violence, some scary cartoon images and mild language</dd>

   <dt>RELEASE COMPANY</dt>
   <dd>Warner Bros.</dd>

   <dt>RUNTIME</dt>
   <dd>90 mins</dd>

   <dt>GENRE</dt>
   <dd>Action/Adventure, Comedies, Childrens, Martial Arts, Superheroes, Ninjas, Animated Characters</dd>

   <dt>BOX OFFICE</dt>
   <dd>$54,132,596</dd>

   <dt>LINKS</dt>
   <dd>
    <br />
    <ul>
     <li><a href="http://www.ninjaturtles.com/">The Official TMNT Site</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/teenage_mutant_ninja_turtles/">RT Review</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://www.rottentomatoes.com/">RT Home</a></li>

    </ul>
   </dd>
  </dl>
 </div>

 <div id="reviews"> 
  <div id="logo">
   <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rottenlarge.png" alt="Rotten" />
   33%
  </div>

  <div id="column-left">
   <p class="reviewer-text">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
    <q>Ditching the cheeky, self-aware wink that helped to excuse the concept's inherent corniness, the movie attempts to look polished and 'cool,' but the been-there animation can't compete with the     then-cutting-edge puppetry of the 1990 live-action movie.</q>    
  </p>    
  <p class="reviewer-info">
       <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
       Peter Debruge <br />
       <span class="publication">Variety</span>
  </p>    

   <p class="reviewer-text">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/fresh.gif" alt="Fresh" />
    <q>TMNT is a fun, action-filled adventure that will satisfy longtime fans and generate a legion of new ones.</q>
   </p>
   <p class="reviewer-info">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
    Todd Gilchrist <br />
    <span class="publication">IGN Movies</span>
   </p>

   <p class="reviewer-text">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
    <q>It stinks!</q>
   </p>
   <p class="reviewer-info">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
    Jay Sherman (unemployed)
   </p>

   <p class="reviewer-text">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
    <q>The rubber suits are gone and they've been redone with fancy computer technology, but that hasn't stopped them from becoming dull.</q>
   </p>
   <p class="reviewer-info">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
    Joshua Tyler <br />
    <span class="publication">CinemaBlend.com</span>
   </p>

   <p class="reviewer-text">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
    <q>This movie sucks because reasons.</q>
   </p>
   <p class="reviewer-info">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
    T. Tally Nobias <br />
    <span class="publication">objectivereviews.com</span>
   </p>
  </div>

  <div id="column-right">
   <p class="reviewer-text">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
    <q>The turtles themselves may look prettier, but are no smarter; torn irreparably from their countercultural roots, our superheroes on the half shell have been firmly co-opted by the industry their creators     once sought to spoof.</q>
  </p>    
  <p class="reviewer-info">
       <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
       Jeannette Catsoulis <br />
       <span class="publication">New York Times</span>
  </p>    

   <p class="reviewer-text">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
    <q>Impersonally animated and arbitrarily plotted, the story appears to have been made up as the filmmakers went along.</q>
   </p>
   <p class="reviewer-info">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
    Ed Gonzalez <br />
    <span class="publication">Slant Magazine</span>
   </p>

   <p class="reviewer-text">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/fresh.gif" alt="Fresh" />
    <q>The striking use of image and motion allows each sequence to leave an impression. It's an accomplished restart to this franchise.</q>
   </p>
   <p class="reviewer-info">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
    Mark Palermo <br />
    <span class="publication">Coast (Halifax, Nova Scotia)</span>
   </p>

   <p class="reviewer-text">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
    <q>The script feels like it was computer generated. This mechanical presentation lacks the cheesy charm of the three live action films.</q>
   </p>
   <p class="reviewer-info">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
    Steve Rhodes <br />
    <span class="publication">Internet Reviews</span>
   </p>

   <p class="reviewer-text">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten" />
    <q>This movie is literally the worst movie ever. I'm not going to explain why. -10000000/10.</q>
   </p>
   <p class="reviewer-info">
    <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/critic.gif" alt="Critic" />
    A. Rheal Kritik <br />
    <span class="publication">Facade Inc.</span>
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <p id="date">(1-10) of 88</p>
</div>

<div id="validators">
 <a href="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/validate-html.php"><img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/w3c-html.png" alt="Valid HTML5" /></a><br />
 <a href="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/validate-css.php"><img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/w3c-css.png" alt="Valid CSS" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, sorry. I must have forgotten to post the image. One moment.

Comment: Sorry, please check again. It's at the top of the page. That should clarify what I mean. If you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: Do you need any more information? I'm happy to clarify further if needed

Comment: @user3450277 I see now, how about adding some additional `margin-bottom` to `.reviewer-info` the same way as I suggested for main container? Making it `20px` should make it fit way more. Default is `1em` margin for `p` elements which you have used.

Comment: @user3450277 If it should go the other way then just remove default `p` margin with e.g. `.reviewer-info { margin: 0; }`. If it is still not what you meant then just draw some arrows on that image :D